# How to divide an object of class "Binary Search Tree" into two objects of class "Binary Search Tree"?

Tags: python, c++

Class "Binary search tree".
Complete the class by including the division method
object of class "Binary search tree" on
two objects of the class "Binary tree
search ". The key to division must be
the value of the item being requested
software and is passed as an argument
method. Items smaller than the key in value,
should be placed in the first tree as well
elements, and larger - in the second.

---

Comment: Which one is it, C++ or Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a binary search Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752944/split-a-binary-search-tree)

Comment: I don't understand how to divide an object of one search engine tree into two objects of search engine tree.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to put an algorithm around the question, may be it helps to get the requirement more clear

//your initial object is obj; you have [root,left,right] in your object; assign your left sub-tree to the new first object;

obj1=obj.left;

//then set the left sub-tree of your initial object to NULL

obj.left=NULL;

//assign remaining tree to new second object

obj2=obj;

Will that help?

Comment: The essence of the task is this. For example, there is a binary search engine consisting of 30 elements. This binary tree has a root, parents and descendants. For a program request, take a specific descendant. From it make a binary search tree. For example, 30 is the root, it has two objects 20 and 25, respectively, they have their descendants, for example, 20 (10 and 15), and 25 (18 and 22). These descendants have parents of other objects, etc. .. I am taking an object, for example 20. From its descendants 10 and 15 I make two binary search trees.